# Primes in a list formed by multiplying $5$ by $a$ and adding $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Take two positive integers $a$ and $b$ that are not multiples of $5.$ Then, construct a list in the following fashion: let the first term be $5,$ and starting with the second number, each number is obtained by multiplying the previous number on the list by $a$ and adding $b.$ What is the maximum number of primes that the list can contain before obtaining the first composite number?

---

I first started the problem by writing out a couple terms in the sequence:
$$5, 5a + b, 5a^2 + ab + b, 5a^3 + a^2b + ab + b, 5a^4 + a^3b + a^2b + ab + b, \cdots$$
I then tried interpreting each term in modulo $5$ but considering each $a, b \pmod{5}$ and expanding was far too long. Considering the terms in modulo $2$ also didn't work since there always exists a way to make the term $\not\equiv 0 \pmod{2}.$

Is there a better way to try and solve this problem besides grueling casework on $a,b, \pmod{5}$?

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: A worksheet about modular arithmetic assigned in a class I'm taking.

Comment: $ab+b=b(a+1)$ When is this a multiple of $5$? What about $a^2b+ab+b=b(a^2+a+1)$?

Comment: Well, $b(a+1)$ is a multiple of $5$ when $a \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ because neither $a,b$ can be multiples of $5,$ and $b(a^2 + a + 1)$ is never a multiple of $5$ because $a^2 + a + 1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{5}.$

Comment: After repeatedly substituting the polynomials into WolframAlpha, it appears that $b(a^{19} + a^{18} + \cdots + a + 1)$ is divisible by $5$ for $a \equiv 1, 2, 3, 4 \pmod{5},$ but I am unsure how to prove this.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed your replies. (You didn't tag @Daniel) What I was hinting at is $a^3+a^2+a+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ when $a\equiv 2\pmod{5}$ or $a\equiv 3\pmod{5}$ and $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ when $a\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and this covers all values of $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note your sequence is a [linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients), i.e.,

$$n_0 = 5, \; \; n_k = an_{k-1} + b \; \forall \; k \ge 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

We could determine $n_k$ explicitly using the method specified in the link, but note instead that, for $a \not\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, as can be seen from your list of initial values (& can be proven using induction), we have

$$n_k \equiv 5a^k + b\left(\frac{a^k-1}{a-1}\right) \pmod{5} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $a^4 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, so $n_4 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. Since $n_4 \gt 5$, it's not a prime and, thus, there's a maximum possible $4$ primes in a row.

For $a \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, we instead have

$$n_k \equiv 5 + kb \pmod{5} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note that $n_k \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ for $1 \le k \le 4$, but that $n_5 \equiv 5 + 5b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, so it's not a prime. This shows there's a maximum possible $5$ initial primes in a row. In particular, $a = 1$ and $b = 6$ give an initial list of $5$ primes of $\{5, 11, 17, 23, 29\}$. This proves that $5$ is the maximum initial number of primes in a row possible in your sequence.

Comment: Congratulations, you have **reinvented the wheel (cycle)**, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Though you've accepted an answer a day prior, it's worth strong emphasis that problems like this can be solved more simply (and more generally) using basic ideas about *permutation cycles* (if these are unfamiliar then see the alternative direct proof in a Remark below). Bringing to the fore the innate $\rm\color{#0a0}{periodic\, (cycle)}$ structure of the sequence $\!\bmod 5\,$ yields the very simple proof below.

**Proof** $\, $ Your sequence $\:\!c_n$ is generated by iteratively applying $\:\!f(x) = ax\:\!\!+\!b\,$ starting at $\,\color{}{c_0 = 5},\,$ i.e. $\,c_n = f^n(c_0).\,$ Viewed $\!\bmod 5\:\!$ note $f\,$ is invertible: $\,f^{-1}(x) \equiv (x\!-\!b)/a,\,$ by $\,a\not\equiv 0,\,$ so $f\,$ is a $\rm\color{#0a0}{permutation}$, and all $\:\!c_k\:\!$ lie in the $\:\!\rm\color{#0a0}{orbit\, ({\it cycle})}$ $f^k(\color{}{c_0})$ of  length at most $\:\!\color{#c00}5 = |\Bbb Z_5|.\,$ So the initial value $\,c_0\equiv 0\pmod{\!5}\,$ repeats as $\,c_k\equiv 0\,$ for $\,0< k\le \color{#c00}5,\,$ so $\,5\mid c_k,\,$ so $\,c_k\,$ is composite (by $c_k$ is increasing so $\,k>0\Rightarrow c_k> c_0\!=\!5).\,$ Thus there are at most $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ initial primes in $\,c_k.\ \ \small\bf QED$

---

**Remark** $ $ If permutation cycles are unknown then we can directly prove the needed $\rm\color{#0a0}{periodicity}$.

**Lemma** $ $ If $f$ is an invertible map on $\Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z \bmod n$ then $f^k(a)\equiv a\pmod{\! n}\,$ for some $\,k\le n$.

**Proof** $\, $ Pigeonhole $\Rightarrow$ among the $\,n\!+\!1\,$ values $\,a,f(a),f^2(a),\cdots, f^n(a)\,$ two are congruent, so for some $\,0\le i< j\le n\!:$ $\,f^j(a)\equiv f^i(a)\,$  so $f^{j-i}(a)\equiv a\,$ by: $ $ ($i$ times) apply $f^{-1}$ (to cancel $f^i)$.

---

Notice this approach does not require *solving* the recurrence (in closed  form). Rather, we only need to prove that the function $f\:\!$  generating the recurrence is *invertible*. Then we may apply a *fundamental* fact - that the cycle graph of an invertible map on a finite set consists of *purely periodic cycles*, i.e. shape oh (o) vs. rho ($\rho$), i.e. no *preperiod* part as in the initial tail of the rho. This basic result is often overlooked, leading to unnecessarily complex proofs - which essentially amount to  **reinventing the wheel (cycle)**. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20wheel%20cycle) for further discussion and examples, including some *nonlinear* recurrences.

Comment: Excellent point!